# How do I directly import a CSV file to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, csv

I need to import large CSV files directly as data frames. As the `read.csv()` function creates a list, I have to then change the list as a data frame using `as.data.frame()`. This is a problem for me as the CSV files are big and storing both the list and data frame will take up a lot of memory.

Since I need to merge multiple CSV files, I think using data frames will be easier as I can join the files on common attributes(columns).

So, this is what I'm doing right now:

```
sample <- read.csv(sample.csv)
sample_df <- as.data.frame(sample)
```

I need a way to import the CSV files directly as data frames.

Comment: read.csv returns a data frame.. Are you running something different? can you do class(read.csv(sample.csv))

Comment: read.csv returns a data frame. run `str(sample)`

Comment: @LiefEsbenshade, the data frame might be huge. str might flood the screen

Comment: `class(sample)` then

Comment: @LiefEsbenshade @StupidWolf I ran ```typeof(sample)``` and it returned a list. So, that is why I thought ```read.csv()``` creates lists instead of a data frame. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok i understand this might be a bit confusing, a data frame combine the behaviour of lists and matrices, so if you do typeof, it's list...typeof will not return data.frame.  try typeof(data.frame(x=1)). it behaves like a list of vectors. But do class() and you can see it's data.frame. Functions rely on class (mostly)

Comment: More specifically, a `data.frame` is precisely a `list` with the added "properties" of: (1) all vectors have the same length; and (2) you can have row names on a frame (not a list), even if some feel row names are not good practice. Other than that, just about anything you can do to a frame, you can do to a list (and vice versa). (Oh, and an odd one, `is.list(mtcars)` is true but `inherits(mtcars,"list")` is not ... weird but just fyi.)